# Unable to Tap on a Tab Button

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

```
ViewInteraction textView1 = onView(allOf(withText("Me"), isDisplayed()));
```

textView1.perform(click());

Works.

The Recorder Records

```
ViewInteraction relativeLayout = onView(
            allOf(withClassName(is("android.widget.RelativeLayout")),
                    withParent(withId(android.R.id.tabs)),
                    isDisplayed()));
    relativeLayout.perform(click());
```

Doesn't work. It will be nice that someone help me not directly using the Text "Me" and approach it with the ID (since Its a multi lingual app)

Comment: can you provide your full code

Answer (score 1):

Just use withId with the TextView id:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.textViewId), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```